# Where method restriction

Tags: c#, generics

I've see generic methods with this `where` keyword like

```
public static void DoStuff<T>() where T :
```

`where` seems to restrict the type of `T` in a specific way.

**Question**: how does this `where` work? Is it only possible to ristrict to interfaces like `where T : IComparable<T>` or are there different ways aswell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [generic type parameter constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

You can constraint T to inherit from a base class, implement an interface, be a reference type, be a value type, have a parameterless constructor...

The compiler checks that the type parameter meets these requirements.

In your case, the constraint allows to call `IComparable<T>` methods in the `DoStuff` method.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer, but I'd add that `where` is a check-constraint only, it doesn't contribute to overload resolution. Strictly thats a *how it doesn't work* information, but it's the most common mis-assumption I know about.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for your comment. All the details about constraints are explained on the MSDN page and your comment already stresses that point so I'll leave the answer as is.